OpenVPN client won't load a target website. On Android and Windows everything works
I've been given an OpenVPN file to access certain domains which, without it, won't load.
The clients in both Android and Windows with this very file work well. Whereas on Linux the target domains won't load.
Others, non-target, domains will load properly.
client
proto tcp
remote xx.xx.xx.xx
port 5517
dev tun
#mssfix 1300
tun-mtu 1500
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
tls-client
#tls-auth 131ta.key 1

#cipher AES-256-CBC
cipher AES-256-GCM
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM
auth SHA256

auth-user-pass
remote-cert-tls server
keepalive 5 15
key-direction 1
#compress lzo
verb 3
tls-version-min 1.2
auth-nocache



# OpenVPN tls key
<tls-auth>
#
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
xxxxx
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
# OpenVPN Diffie-Hellman - not needed for client
# OpenVPN CA
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

# OpenVPN user certificate .crt:
<cert>

Certificate:
    Data:
        xxxx
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</cert>

# OpenVPN user key: .key
<key>

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

</key>


What's the matter?
The systemd service systemd-resolved is running
And the content   /etc/resolv.conf of is:
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 9.9.9.9


# IPv6 nameservers:
nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1111
nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1001

